# PHP's mkdir function trouble on Windows

Tags: php, mkdir

I am working on a command line program in PHP and I am having trouble, my first problem is when I call PHP's `mkdir()` it is giving me this error

```
Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in 
E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\OptimizeImage.php
on line 196
```

I then read in the PHP docs a user comment that said that the forward slash `/` does not work with this method under Windows but on Unix.

So I then changed my code to change them to backslashes but it did not change anything for me, I still got the same error on the same line.

Here is the code below can someone help me figure this out please

```
// I tried both of these below
$tmp_path = '\tmp\e0bf7d6';
//$tmp_path = '/tmp/e0bf7d6';

echo $tmp_path;

mkdir($tmp_path);
```

Comment: you can not access `tmp` folder via PHP. fist u need to use `move_uploaded_files()`

Comment: Have you tried using getcwd() to see from where the script is executing? Also, the third parameter of the function enables recursive creation. So if the directory you are trying to create has a parent directory that doesn't exist (yet) it will be created instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Try `[\\]` instead `[\]`. Maybe correct your problem.

Comment: What if you add drive letter (e.g. c:\tmp\e0b7df) or ommit first (back)slash - tmp\e0b7df ?

Comment: I normally change dir `chdir` to where I want to create the folders and then use the recursion like the answer suggests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual problem is that [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/mkdir)  only creates one subdirectory per call, but you passed it a path of two non-existant directories. You would normally have to do this step by step:

```
mkdir("/tmp");
mkdir("/tmp/e0b093u209");
mkdir("/tmp/e0b093u209/thirddir");
```

Or use the third parameter shortcut:

```
mkdir("/tmp/e0b093u209", 0777, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you this was driving me about insane, thank you thank you

Comment: Sadly I'm already using the 2nd and 3rd argument and it still says `no such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

I normally use the following line as a constant and I put in a global file to be used through my sites.

```
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

That should fix the separator problem. I would also try the recursive property found in mkdir that will allow you to make the nested structure. 
Please see the foillowing, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

You will notice that you needs to call mkdir like below.

```
mkdir ($path, $mode, true)
```